# Laravel and storage

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-artisan

I have made a Laravel site and it works fine on my pc (don't they all :P)
I used `php artistan storage:link` to make a link to my storage so i can use storeAs. Now I have the following problem. My hosting doesnt have a console and can't make the symlink for me. How can I still access the right directory for my image upload/delete/etc stuff? I now have this:

```
  $request->file('blogIMG')->storeAs('public/trips/'. $request->get('tripName') . '/' .$blog->blogName .'/', $request->get('id').'.png');
```

I would really like to stay with my host, so can I fix this in my code?

Comment: Your hosting does not have a console? That would be very strange... They always have SSH access to their own servers. So it they don't give you SSH access (also strange), they can do that for you

Comment: You can call artisan in app by facade: `Artisan::call('storage:link');`